# Laravel return relationship data with condition

Tags: laravel

Excuse me,
I have receipts table and carton table which connected with hasmanythrough
so i want to return receipt with specific id with carton table data relation
but with condition that it returns from 'startnumber' to 'endnumber'
so far i've tried with this query but no success

```
$receipt = Receipt::find($id);
$fstart = $receipt->no_resi.'/'.$start;
$fend = $receipt->no_resi.'/'.$end;
// it will return something like for example : $fstart = CJAA0017/1 || $fend CJAA0017/5

        $receipt = $receipt->with(['carton' => function ($query) {
            $query->whereBetween('no_ctn', [$fstart, $fend]);
        }])->get();
```

EDIT:
Receipt Model

```
class Receipt extends Model
{
    public function receipt_detail() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Receipt_detail', 'receipt_id', 'id');
    }

    public function carton() 
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Model\Carton_number', 'App\Model\Receipt_detail', 'receipt_id', 'detail_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Receipt_detail Model

```
class Receipt_detail extends Model
{
    public function carton() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Carton_number', 'detail_id', 'id');
    }

    public function receipt()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Receipt', 'receipt_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Carton_number model

```
class Carton_number extends Model
{
    public function receipt_detail()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Receipt_detail', 'detail_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, TIA :)

Comment: please provide your model and relationship code as well.

Answer (score 0):

`$fstart` and `$fend` is called inside a closure but you haven't passed the variables into the closure so you could do the following to pass the variables.

```
$receipt = $receipt->with(['carton' => function ($query) use ($fstart, $fend) {
    $query->whereBetween('no_ctn', [$fstart, $fend]);
}])->get();
```

Also this may work when $start and $end is single digit but when it is more than one digit it may not work because of string comparison.
A better way is to extract the number from `no_ctn` field and compare them with start and end.

```
$receipt = $receipt->with(['carton' => function ($query) use ($receipt, $start, $end) {
    $query->whereRaw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(no_ctn, '/', 1) = ?", [$receipt->no_resi])
        ->whereRaw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(no_ctn, '/', -1) >= ?", [$start])
        ->whereRaw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(no_ctn, '/', -1) <= ?", [$end]);
}])->get();
```

You pass `$receipt, $start, $end` directly to the closure and extract the value from `no_ctn` field to compare. Assuming you are using mysql you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX function to extract the field value from the left and right of the slash.

Comment: i've got error saying : 'A non-numeric value encountered' on line whereRaw('SUBSTRING_INDEX(no_ctn, '/', 1) = ?', [$receipt->no_resi])

Comment: which line was that?

Comment: @nehemmiah  is no_ctn nullable? and does it always have a value?

Comment: no its not, and yes. it will create data when receipt is created

Comment: how about $receipt->no_resi? does it always have a value?

Comment: yes, its not nullable as it will be used pretty much everywhere

Comment: sorry, I messed up the quote and and double quote, updated the answer.

Comment: np, i got the data but it returns multiple data and the data doesnt match with the one i want. hence why i used : Receipt::find($id) on earlier query. say i find($id) that should return CJAA0017, instead it returns data QOAA0015, URAA0016, and CJAA0017

Comment: should be fine, we already have it checked here ->whereRaw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(no_ctn, '/', 1) = ?", [$receipt->no_resi])